# SSL WordPress site not displaying properly in older browsers

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have Comodo Positive SSL installed on my WordPress site www.celinelasvegas.com. I have changed the general site settings to https, used "Really Simple SSL" plugin and forced https in my htaccess file.

Every works fine and I get the green padlock in broswers, however in older browsers the website display is totally messed up. Is this down to the SSL certificate I'm using or something in my setup?

Many thanks

Clare

Comment: Define older browsers?

Comment: In work, the pcs are old and they have IE8 - screen grab here -> 

http://tinypic.com/r/28anvap/9